# How to read/write matrices in Fortran?

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have a simple Fortran code below, where I am reading a matrix from a text file and then passing it on to a subroutine. But when it is read in the subroutine it gives out a garbage value. I can't seem to figure out whats wrong with the code?

```
program main
implicit none
real, dimension(:,:), allocatable :: mat
open (unit=99, file='inp.txt', status='old', action='read')
allocate(mat(2,2))
read(99, *), mat
CALL fun(mat)
end

subroutine fun(mat)
dimension mat(2,2)
write(*,*) mat
return
end
```

The matrix `mat` is read in as  `[2 4; 2 10]`, but when displayed within the subroutine it gives out `[1073741824 1082130432; 1073741824 1092616192]`.

Comment: Your mat has an implicit type of integer, but you are passing it reals... Better use modules and implicit none everywhere...

Comment: Thanks. Including `Implicit none` in the subroutine and declaring mat as `real` worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use implicit variable declaration in Fortran, variables starting with `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, `M`, or `N` denote integers (by default).

Since you only have `implicit none` in the scope of the main program but not for the subroutine, your `real` array `mat` is interpreted as an integer in the subroutine. Hence the garbage.

Simply declaring `mat` as `real` in the subroutine should fix your problem.